# my contacts lost

Tags: contacts, sim-card

I moved all contacts to the sim, on Android.
now there are no notes or contact photos.
no backup exists
I moved them back to the phone and still not exist, what can I do to retrieve them?

Comment: If there's no backup (e.g. synced to Google Contacts or other providers), then I'm afraid it might be not easily recoverable since SIM contacts are very basic and mostly only store name and phone number...

Answer (score 2):

Usually an address book entry on a SIM card consists of only two fields:

1. Telephone number
2. Name

All other fields you had used before moving the contacts to the SIM card are unsupported and therefore got lost when you chose to move them to the SIM cards.

Moving them back to the Android/Google address book does not recover the additional fields as the SIM card does not contain this data.

The only way to recover deleted contact is if you had synced the contact to your Google account.

Google Contacts allow to recover deleted contact, e.g. via web UI: https://contacts.google.com/

Open the settings menu (the gear icon on the top, left side) and select the entry **Undo changes** (or some similar text). Then you can select the date/time span you want to undo.

AFAIK the [Google Contacts app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts) also provides the functionality to undo changes in a similar way.